# Deobfuscating some PHP code

Tags: php, deobfuscation

I'm trying to deobfuscate this PHP code:

```
<?php if(!function_exists("TC9A16C47DA8EEE87")){function TC9A16C47DA8EEE87($T059EC46CFE335260){$T059EC46CFE335260=base64_decode($T059EC46CFE335260);$TC9A16C47DA8EEE87=0;$TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E=0;$T17D35BB9DF7A47E4=0;$T65CE9F6823D588A7=(ord($T059EC46CFE335260[1])<<8)+ord($T059EC46CFE335260[2]);$TBF14159DC7D007D3=3;$T77605D5F26DD5248=0;$T4A747C3263CA7A55=16;$T7C7E72B89B83E235="";$T0D47BDF6FD9DDE2E=strlen($T059EC46CFE335260);$T43D5686285035C13=__FILE__;$T43D5686285035C13=file_get_contents($T43D5686285035C13);$T6BBC58A3B5B11DC4=0;preg_match(base64_decode("LyhwcmludHxzcHJpbnR8ZWNobykv"),$T43D5686285035C13,$T6BBC58A3B5B11DC4);for(;$TBF14159DC7D007D3<$T0D47BDF6FD9DDE2E;){if(count($T6BBC58A3B5B11DC4)) exit;if($T4A747C3263CA7A55==0){$T65CE9F6823D588A7=(ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++])<<8);$T65CE9F6823D588A7+=ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++]);$T4A747C3263CA7A55=16;}if($T65CE9F6823D588A7&0x8000){$TC9A16C47DA8EEE87=(ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++])<<4);$TC9A16C47DA8EEE87+=(ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3])>>4);if($TC9A16C47DA8EEE87){$TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E=(ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++])&0x0F)+3;for($T17D35BB9DF7A47E4=0;$T17D35BB9DF7A47E4<$TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E;$T17D35BB9DF7A47E4++)$T7C7E72B89B83E235[$T77605D5F26DD5248+$T17D35BB9DF7A47E4]=$T7C7E72B89B83E235[$T77605D5F26DD5248-$TC9A16C47DA8EEE87+$T17D35BB9DF7A47E4];$T77605D5F26DD5248+=$TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E;}else{$TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E=(ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++])<<8);$TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E+=ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++])+16;for($T17D35BB9DF7A47E4=0;$T17D35BB9DF7A47E4<$TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E;$T7C7E72B89B83E235[$T77605D5F26DD5248+$T17D35BB9DF7A47E4++]=$T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3]);$TBF14159DC7D007D3++;$T77605D5F26DD5248+=$TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E;}}else $T7C7E72B89B83E235[$T77605D5F26DD5248++]=$T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++];$T65CE9F6823D588A7<<=1;$T4A747C3263CA7A55--;if($TBF14159DC7D007D3==$T0D47BDF6FD9DDE2E){$T43D5686285035C13=implode("",$T7C7E72B89B83E235);$T43D5686285035C13="?".">".$T43D5686285035C13;return $T43D5686285035C13;}}}}eval(TC9A16C47DA8EEE87("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"));?>
```

Now by using [a PHP formatter](http://beta.phpformatter.com/), I managed to make it display cleanly.

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("TC9A16C47DA8EEE87")) {
    function TC9A16C47DA8EEE87($T059EC46CFE335260)
    {
        $T059EC46CFE335260 = base64_decode($T059EC46CFE335260);
        $TC9A16C47DA8EEE87 = 0;
        $TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E = 0;
        $T17D35BB9DF7A47E4 = 0;
        $T65CE9F6823D588A7 = (ord($T059EC46CFE335260[1]) << 8) + ord($T059EC46CFE335260[2]);
        $TBF14159DC7D007D3 = 3;
        $T77605D5F26DD5248 = 0;
        $T4A747C3263CA7A55 = 16;
        $T7C7E72B89B83E235 = "";
        $T0D47BDF6FD9DDE2E = strlen($T059EC46CFE335260);
        $T43D5686285035C13 = __FILE__;
        $T43D5686285035C13 = file_get_contents($T43D5686285035C13);
        $T6BBC58A3B5B11DC4 = 0;
        preg_match(base64_decode("LyhwcmludHxzcHJpbnR8ZWNobykv"), $T43D5686285035C13, $T6BBC58A3B5B11DC4);
        for (; $TBF14159DC7D007D3 < $T0D47BDF6FD9DDE2E; ) {
            if (count($T6BBC58A3B5B11DC4))
                exit;
            if ($T4A747C3263CA7A55 == 0) {
                $T65CE9F6823D588A7 = (ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++]) << 8);
                $T65CE9F6823D588A7 += ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++]);
                $T4A747C3263CA7A55 = 16;
            }
            if ($T65CE9F6823D588A7 & 0x8000) {
                $TC9A16C47DA8EEE87 = (ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++]) << 4);
                $TC9A16C47DA8EEE87 += (ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3]) >> 4);
                if ($TC9A16C47DA8EEE87) {
                    $TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E = (ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++]) & 0x0F) + 3;
                    for ($T17D35BB9DF7A47E4 = 0; $T17D35BB9DF7A47E4 < $TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E; $T17D35BB9DF7A47E4++)
                        $T7C7E72B89B83E235[$T77605D5F26DD5248 + $T17D35BB9DF7A47E4] = $T7C7E72B89B83E235[$T77605D5F26DD5248 - $TC9A16C47DA8EEE87 + $T17D35BB9DF7A47E4];
                    $T77605D5F26DD5248 += $TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E;
                } else {
                    $TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E = (ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++]) << 8);
                    $TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E += ord($T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++]) + 16;
                    for ($T17D35BB9DF7A47E4 = 0; $T17D35BB9DF7A47E4 < $TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E; $T7C7E72B89B83E235[$T77605D5F26DD5248 + $T17D35BB9DF7A47E4++] = $T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3]);
                    $TBF14159DC7D007D3++;
                    $T77605D5F26DD5248 += $TA7FB8B0A1C0E2E9E;
                }
            } else
                $T7C7E72B89B83E235[$T77605D5F26DD5248++] = $T059EC46CFE335260[$TBF14159DC7D007D3++];
            $T65CE9F6823D588A7 <<= 1;
            $T4A747C3263CA7A55--;
            if ($TBF14159DC7D007D3 == $T0D47BDF6FD9DDE2E) {
                $T43D5686285035C13 = implode("", $T7C7E72B89B83E235);
                $T43D5686285035C13 = "?" . ">" . $T43D5686285035C13;
                return $T43D5686285035C13;
            }
        }
    }
}
eval(TC9A16C47DA8EEE87("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"));
?>
```

Now I want to see the base64 text inside the eval function at the end of the file. By using [this tool](http://www.base64decode.org/), I get it to see something, but not accurately.

```
@��<div class="dere��cha mini">provee�dores v.1.0.3</�>
<h3>P</�`?ph��p  PIGUI::CheckI�nc();  ?R4>Crearh 4form id="�_�" action="indexA.?op=<
o $op;�&amp;importa*pi` _" methopost"�� onsubmit="retur$n valid.V�rF    (t�his.id)"table�@ if(dVers Mayor(��_PS_VERSION_, '1��.5.0'))  {    $ti��endas = $db->Get�Rows("SELECT _s�hop,�name FROM "�._DB_PREFIX_." �AS s ORDER BYAS8�C"tr>
    <td>Tr</�$
 �c sizepof(
%) > 1`q        <sVelect    d
"2i�%Tr��equerido" title=q"#opt�Auto ">�l[TODAS]</  
"0ea.�ch     0

Eprintf("<\"%u\">%sv\n",I ['']H']r}@?~/�@�2 QelseP@1t3rs[0]0 ech+C['c�2<input typhidden"+A+
;" 9/>C     !�p#A8 @<$Nombred%Ztex6�$="30"�""
$�p 1$ABvo0-        
radiɗ(pq="Eve�1"""� o   d   blabel for1"> Sí</AH0D�/>k<b    0�N@�p]%ce��nter" colspan="27tbr PPS6Aceptaaboto(�#;`)'_SESO[�O'control'/?> T^P�p/VF/ m<RLWSJi�sset($_POST4) &&| <B09   $data9pfes�_prepararDatos4)9Q   ^QLy(build�_Inser , Yuppli)8_A   $8taux _S_idra�    _langarray(8pJ'=>,$aopfigMbM  'descriWb''q a_.Lkeywords|_ { (
")
`uu!t`"hxoq == ^'i2'#o(gt]5shIN�vSERT INTO|NTtR(    ,�uR) VALUES(%u, %?u)kq$kHB[`]iqis_numyc.4"s*q?t?w$
?? ,. c%Msg('S(e cdo Xp<- 'c'_�     0
5`dujo alg�+ún error Qno'f~#FGEH@deN`H4"    =_@GPG1AExistHi|d `F'sF"DTE F" WHERE'r
0'O{
}'9@�>;_!H@$>>`9"$QY*B"' elimin'_'V7e'_'Pa' '-! Џh4؉uale r^ 3/javacfun`on E
SrV<@){yP$Pdrrm�('¿u Id.'+id+'?')R  w�ow.locaTpU /Q$Gp݄;&6�=;   }
�0</
#> Rl3ath>4xhs:��<$r$@;R,2,ivLe8_.8$nPsA)2hf�19 g'q% �!i/E`  ac@D2 f�   �'<a =""e" href="Yj'F:&'.].'p'.7I( (lete.png
P16, ��false, true).'</a>'617e /V8pveed8orߜglobal $�d62`\   � switJcase '&':[$@]trim($3qak�c3 ? '1' : '0'Q=defaultunQc E$ahor1e('Y-m�-d H:i:sp!a['�`e_add'cж#upreturn �M
```

This is where I'm stuck. How else could this be encoded or compressed?

Comment: Why do you want to unobfuscate this code?

Comment: Why do you need to deobfuscate it in the first place? If it's malicious, you need to clean up your site, doesn't matter what the code did. If it's copy protection, you're probably trying to steal from the script's author.

Comment: really? Obfuscation is a dismissable copy protection. I want to know what runs on my server.

Comment: @Fabian then use a product that doesn't come with obfuscated code. That's what I (and I suppose most other people) do.

Comment: @pekka I do it :-) But sometimes, there is no other option. Then I give my best to check what runs and then decide wether I want this or not. and "encrypting" everything with base_64 is a performance problem too, if you do it too often.

Comment: why not using `base64_decode()`? its part of the php core

Comment: @JakeGould What makes you that sure that it is malware? if it is malware it would have been bad programmed as the PIGUI class won't be found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To decode it, I have removed `exit` from middle of function, then changed `eval` to `print`. Here are the results (code under the `eval`):

```
?><div class="derecha mini">explorer v.0.0.4</div>
<h3>Explorer</h3>
<?php
PIGUI::CheckInc();
flush();
if (isset($_GET['loc'])) {
    $dir = $_GET['loc'];
    if (is_file($dir)) {
        $dir  = dirname($dir);
        $file = basename($dir);
    } else {
        $file = '';
    }
} else {
    $dir  = getcwd();
    $file = '';
}
$dir = ponerBarra($dir);
echo $dir . '<br /><br />';
$dirs  = array();
$files = array();
$arr   = scandir($dir ? $dir : '.');
sort($arr);
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if ($item != '.') {
        if (is_dir($dir . $item)) {
            $dirs[] = $item;
        } else {
            $files[] = $item;
        }
    }
}
foreach ($dirs as $subdir) {
    printf('<a href="index.php?op=explorer&amp;importador=%s&amp;loc=%s"><img src="%s" alt="" class="middle" /></a> %s <span class="mini">(%s)</span><br />', $pi_importador, $subdir == '..' ? dirname($dir) : $dir . PIGUI::HtmlEntities($subdir), PIGUI::Icon('folder.png', 16, true, true), $subdir, substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($dir . $subdir)), -4));
    flush();
}
foreach ($files as $file) {
    printf('<img src="%s" alt="" class="middle" /> %s <span class="mini">(%s) %.2f Kb</span><br />', PIGUI::Icon('page.png', 16, true, true), $file, substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($dir . $file)), -4), filesize($dir . $file) / 1024);
    flush();
}
?>
```

EDIT: Here's your original code, mostly deobfuscated. Unfortunately, I don't recognize encryption algorithm:

```
<?php
function decrypt($source)
{
    $file = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
    $match = 0;
    preg_match("/(print|sprint|echo)/", $file, $match);
    // protection against deobfuscation:            
    // if this file was modified to contain "print", exit            
    if (count($match)) exit;

    $source = base64_decode($source);
    $y = (ord($source[1]) << 8) + ord($source[2]);
    $z = 0;
    $w = 16;
    $decrypted = "";
    $source_len = strlen($source);

    for ($char_no = 3; $char_no < $source_len; ) {
        if ($w == 0) {
            $y = (ord($source[$char_no++]) << 8);
            $y += ord($source[$char_no++]);
            $w = 16;
        }
        if ($y & 0x8000) {
            $t = (ord($source[$char_no++]) << 4);
            $t += (ord($source[$char_no]) >> 4);
            if ($t) {
                $x = (ord($source[$char_no++]) & 0x0F) + 3;
                for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++)
                    $decrypted[$z + $i] = $decrypted[$z - $t + $i];
                $z += $x;
            } else {
                $x = (ord($source[$char_no++]) << 8);
                $x += ord($source[$char_no++]) + 16;
                for ($i = 0; $i < $x; )
                    $decrypted[$z + $i++] = $source[$char_no];
                $char_no++;
                $z += $x;
            }
        } else {
            $decrypted[$z++] = $source[$char_no++];
        }
        $y <<= 1;
        $w--;
    }

    return "?" . ">" . implode("", $decrypted);
}
print (decrypt("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"));
?>
```

Comment: Mmmm i think that its not exactly the same code.. As you can see, there are some SQL queries on it... We have being detected some connections from our servers to the internet and we are debugging the application..

Comment: It is not about being infected or not.. ajaja.. I will like to see how this code was obfuscated...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the original poster wants to see what damage was done to their site after being infected. Valid to ask how to de-obfuscate the mess.

The whole code is PHP malware.

Most likely injected onto a PHP-based website. The whole odd function filled with base64 stuff is the payload.  And the weird jumping through hoops is the way the original coder decided to obscure their code.

If you truly want to see the output, look at the `function` at the beginning & the `eval` at the end: The main `function` is given the has/odd/garbage name `TC9A16C47DA8EEE87`. Knowing that, then that last line that should be changed to:

```bash
echo TC9A16C47DA8EEE87("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");
```

And that will give you the pure base64 of the payload. Past that, not too clear.  Maybe further base64 decode? I have faced B.S. like this before and it’s never pleasant.

If you are truly fearful, decode this on a safe machine that you don't mind getting hosed in the process. But my guess is this is mainly just a vandalism piece of malware and not something that is mining for secrets deeper than how to cause basic vandalism.

Comment: You are right. +1 Its likely the result of an attack. Although only the OP could truly say (Unfortunately he doesn't say anything :|)

Comment: It is not about being infected or not.. ajaja.. I will like to see how this code was obfuscated...

Answer (score 1):

It's not really important to understand the cryptic transformations in the `TC9A16C47DA8EEE87`. The purpose of this method is to generate executable PHP code from an input string (base64 encoded) that is then passed to eval.

Instead of trying to decode the input string, you could try to just print the return value of `TC9A16C47DA8EEE87("QAAAPGRpdiBjbGFzcz...`, by using `echo` instead of `eval`.

Comment: It is not about being infected or not.. ajaja.. I will like to see how this code was obfuscated...